# How can I set viewbag for SelectListItem to search when paging?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, search, html.dropdownlistfor

How can I set a viewbag to dropdownlist like I set for @Html.Textbox in my code. Because I want to keep value of dropdowlist when I go next page by PagedList

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Account", FormMethod.Get))
{
  <div class="inDiv">
    <label>Filter data :</label>
  </div>
  <div class="inDiv">
    @Html.DropDownList("key", new List<SelectListItem>()
    {
      new SelectListItem{ Text="[ Theo kiểu ]"},
      new SelectListItem{Value="accountname", Text="Account Name"},
      new SelectListItem{Value="fullname", Text="Full Name"},
    }, new { @class = "form-control input-sm" })
  </div>
  <div class="inDiv">
    @Html.TextBox("SearchString", ViewBag.CurrentFilter as string, new { @class = "form-control input-sm", @placeholder = "input here ..." })
  </div>
  <div class="inDiv">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" value="Search">
  </div>
}
```

Comment: Use a model/view model and bind your controls to it

Comment: thank @StephenMuecke I have resolved this issue :)

Answer (score 0):

On Controller ActionMethod

```
var Cities = new List<SelectListItem>();
Cities.Add(new SelectListItem { Name = "Nagpur", Id = "1" });
Cities.Add(new SelectListItem { Name = "Pune", Id = "2" });
Cities.Add(new SelectListItem { Name = "Mumbai", Id = "3" });
Cities.Add(new SelectListItem { Name = "Delhi", Id = "4" });

ViewBag.CityList = new SelectList(Cities, "Id", "Name");
```

On View

```
@Html.DropDownList("DispCity", ViewBag.CityList)
```